# find real number using two percentage.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

Would like to shorten my request and what do find equation for my below question.

If **69%** is *27.35* and **79%** is **27.39** then what will be value for ***70%***.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think the number match up  correctly. I get different results from those two values.

Comment: @A---B. I'm no maths expert. but i guess that we need to apply linear equation method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a linear equation/function you're looking for, it's quite easy: the difference between 69% and 79% is 10%; in the course of that, the value increases by 0.04. That means it increases by 0.004 for each 1%, and the value corresponding to 70% must be 27.354.